# Выводы по финансовому анализу в датафрейме pandas при срабатывании определенных событий или значений

Tags: pandas, dataframe, форматирование

у меня есть датафрейм с различными показателями. Необходимо сформировать новую колонку с комментариям, если какое-либо значение выходит за определенные рамки.
df_ratio:

```
Name    OGRN  Sales Equity Debt Net_profit   ER    Sales_dyn fin_gearing
Lutik   1234   200    5     10     3        0.001    -0.1       0.5
Pestik  2345   1000   35    20     -10       0.5      0.3       3
Cvet    3456   260    10     0      2        -5       -0.3      -0.4
Drev    4567   350    40     5      10        0.3     0.2       0.3
```

Пытался создать функцию, которая проходит по датафрейму и при обнаружении критических показателей пишет соответствующие комментарии в новую колонку:

Критические значения:

```
df_ratio['ER'] < 0.05 - ER is poor       
df_ratio['ER'] < 0 -    Negative equity
df_ratio['Net_profit'] < 0 - Lossess
df_ratio['fin_gearing'] > 1 - High debt level
df_ratio['Sales_dyn'] < 0 Sales dropped
```

Если не одно из вышеперечисленных условий не срабатывает то Комментарии Sound Financial position

Сперва пытался загнать все функцию и через цикл пройтись по всем колонкам и если что-то срабатывает, то делать append в пустой лист через форматирование строки f"". Но все не так :((( Запутался!!!

Каким необходимо видеть итоговый df
df_ratio:

```
Name    OGRN  Sales Equity Debt Net_profit   ER    Sales_dyn fin_gearing    Comments
Lutik   1234   200    5     10     3        0.001    -0.1       0.5         ER is poor 0.001(Equity=5),
                                                                            Sales droped -0.1(Sales=200)
Pestik  2345   1000   35    20     -10       0.5      0.3       3           Losses -10, High debt 
                                                                            level 3 (Debt=20)
Cvet    3456   260    10     0      2        -5       -0.3      -0.4        Negative equity -5
                                                                           Sales droped -0.3 (Sales=260)      
Drev    4567   350    40     5      10        0.3     0.2       0.3         Sound financial position
```

Буду признателен за помощь

Comment: как быть если сработает сразу несколько условий?

Comment: @MaxU в том то и делать при срабатывание нескольких условий они все пишутся в комментарии - хоть все условия если сработают...чем больше условий срабатывает тем хуже дела у компании

Comment: Можете привести соответствующий пример результата?

Comment: @MaxU как один из видов комментариев при срабатывании все условий: ER is poor 0.03 (Equity=20), Losses -25, High debt level 4.5 (Debt=90),  Sales dropped -0.5 (Sales=300)

Comment: Я бы просто сделал отдельные булевы колонки по результатам проверки каждого из признаков и дальше уже с ними что-нибудь придумывал.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо да этим как раз и играюсь сейчас, написал функцию которая обходит датафрейм и по условиям, соответствующим в колонках добавляет в пустой лист все комментарии через append, но как то все туго и с ошибками :(((

Comment: @Pavel Лучше не обходите, а как-нибудь через `apply` что ли попробуйте может

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня как-то так получилось:

```
def neg_comments(df):
    comment = []
    if df['ER'] < 0.05 and df['ER'] > 0:
       comment.append(f"ER is poor: {df['ER']"}
    elif df['ER'] < 0:
       comment.append(f"Negative equity: {df['ER']"}
    if df['Net_profit'] <0:
       comment.append(f"Losses {df['Net_profit']"}   
    if df['fin_gearing'] > 1:
       comment.append(f"High debt level {df['fin_gearing']"}
   if df['Sales_dyn'] < 0:
       comment.append(f"Sales dropped by {df['Sales_dyn']"}
   df['Comments'] = ', '.join(comment)
   return df

df_ratio = df_ration.apply(neg_comments, axis=1)
```